# How do I store objects of sub classes in array?

Tags: java, inheritance, abstract

The question is to create objects of both sub classes and store them in an array .
So I create a abstract Super class and made a method area abstract after that I created the two sub classes and implemented that method on the main method I declared array and given the values this is it. I am new here so sorry if I'm asking it in wrong way.
And yes the output should be the area and types of two figure.

```
package Geometric;

public abstract class GeometricFigure {

    int height;
    int width;
    String type;
    int area;


    public GeometricFigure(int height, int width) {
        //super();
        this.height = height;
        this.width = width;
    }



    public abstract int area();
}

package Geometric;

public class Square extends GeometricFigure {

    public Square(int height, int width) {
        super(height,width);


    }
    public int area(){

        return height * width;

    }

}

package Geometric;

public class Triangle extends GeometricFigure {

    public Triangle(int height, int width) {
        super(height ,width);

    }
    public int area() {
        return (height*width)/2;
    }
}
package Geometric;

public class UseGeometric {

    public static void main(String args[]) {

        GeometricFigure[] usegeometric = { new Square(12, 15), new Triangle(21, 18) };

        for (int i = 0; i < usegeometric.length; i++) {

            System.out.println(usegeometric[i]);
            usegeometric[i].area();

            System.out.println();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: ehm, you store them in an array ... exactly like you did? what exactly isn't working?

Comment: @Stultuske 
yes I did but output of mine is wrong, the output of above code is -Geometric.Square@19dfb72a

Geometric.Triangle@17f6480

I cant understand this error

Comment: check my answer, you'll need to overwrite toString in your two concrete classes

Comment: @nihalsrivastava, you need to override toString() method in your subclasses, e.g.: `@Override public String toString() { return "Triangle"; }` in `Triangle` class. Or you can make your toString method returns all the data about your figure: name, area etc.

Comment: yes thanks its working fine. thankyou all

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You already are storing both elements in an array, I think your question is more related to this part:

```
usegeometric[i].area();

        System.out.println();
```

You get the area of both elements, but you don't assign it to a variable, and you don't do anything with it. Change those lines of code to this:

```
System.out.println("Area: " + usegeometric[i].area());
```

EDIT:

Geometric.Square@19dfb72a Geometric.Triangle@17f6480

This is the kind of output you can expect because you didn't overwrite the `toString` method in your classes. 
If you don't, it will take the inherited version of Object, which prints [this information](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#toString())

--
In your `Square` class, add this:

```
public String toString() {
  return "Square - area = " + area();
}
```

or something similar, depending on what you want to be printed. (And a similar adjustment to your `Triangle` class).
At this time, you are printing `Object`'s version of `toString`, since you didn't provide a new one. By overwriting that method, you should get the output you want after turning your loop into:

```
for (int i = 0; i < usegeometric.length; i++) {
   System.out.println(usegeometric[i]);
}
```

What `println` actually does, is not print the object itself, but a String representation of the object, which is provided by the `toString` method.

Comment: what do you mean, it doesn't determine the type of figure?

Comment: i mean that it should also return that type of figure like square or triangle

Comment: I overwrite the toString() method in classes now its working fine thanks

Comment: If this solved your question, can you mark the answer as accepted? that way, other people will know the question was answered

Answer (score 0):

public class UseGeometric {

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    GeometricFigure[] usegeometric = { new Square(12, 15), new Triangle(21, 18) };

    for (int i = 0; i < usegeometric.length; i++) {


        System.out.println("Area is: " + usegeometric[i].area());

    }
} }
```